# discord.py how to assign roles using user id? Is there any way to get discord.Member by User Id?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

basicly This code gets list of users that needs to be assigned the role get their user data and store them as a list. But when I try to assign role to them, it occurs **discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_roles'** error. How should I fix it? Is there any better way to do it?       The command I put in is ".assignrole @member1,@member2 role_name".

```
@bot.command(aliases=['assignrole'])
async def shiritori(ctx, message, role: discord.Role):
    memberlist =[]
    member = message.split(',')
    for x in range(0,len(member)):  
        member_id = int(member[x].strip('<@!>'))
        memberadd = await bot.fetch_user(member_id)
        memberlist.append(memberadd)
        await ctx.send(memberlist[x])
        await memberlist[x].add_roles(memberlist[x], role)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the discord.py [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=add_roles#discord.Member.add_roles) you are parametering the add_roles function wrong. You just have to pass it your role variable, no need to specify the member in the parameters as you are calling the function of a member instance. So your last line should look like this:

```
await memberlist[x].add_roles(role)
```

I hope this fixes your issue.